# Python syntax error when returning two lists from function

Tags: python, list, return

I want to return two lists from a function as follows:

```
for index, file in enumerate(files):
    file_path = dir_path + file
    image_listnew, label_listnew = reader.read_gnt_image(file_path))
```

but I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". The function read_gnt_image() returns two lists and worked with a variation of the code I have above, and I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: You have two closing parentheses after `file_path`. Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra parentheses at the end.

L1, L2 = func() will work if you return two separate strings.

Comment: I haven't yet eaten today, i guess you can tell!